# JsFiddle.net - MooShellEditor is not defined

Tags: google-chrome, jsfiddle

When I try to access jsfiddle.net from my machine, browser doesn't load the page correctly. I checked on console and it shows following errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) jsfiddle.net/js/EditorCM.js?nojobofferinsidebar:290
Uncaught ReferenceError: MooShellEditor is not defined jsfiddle.net/:89
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'editor' of undefined jsfiddle.net/js/Actions.js?nojobofferinsidebar:151
```

I tried on Chrome, Firefox and IE but getting errors on all. Is there any specific browser settings? I can see it's working on different machine.

Comment: Interesting, are you sure you don't have some sort of adAware, AntiVirus, Browser Protector programs running on your OS that would block JavaScript from being downloaded? See in the Network tab of chrome's developer Tools if you get any 404 or blocked errors.

Comment: Also, are these errors present when you go to jsfiddle.net or to an existing project?

Answer (score 0):

Posting reply after long time but hope it will be helpful to someone.

If you have Proxy server settings selected under LAN Settings of IE (Tools -> Internet Options -> Connections tab -> LAN settings) then the errors were shown on the console. If I select Automatatically Detect Settings then it worked fine.

If you start Fiddler on your machine then it will select proxy server settings. Probably, that was causing an issue for me.